# How to make a condition to select A and B in a column but not A or B alone?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A:

```
col1    col2
nameA   A
nameA   B
nameB   A
nameC   B
.........
```

I want to make a condition so that all the values of nameA with **both** A and B, but **not only** A or B itself, will be selected. How can I do this?

Using **IN** is not working since if only A or B then the condition is still giving result.

Expected result:

```
col1    col2
nameA   A
nameA   B
```

Not expected resut:

```
col1    col2
nameA   A
```

Or

```
col1   col2
nameA  B
```

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE col1 = 'NameA'`?

Comment: @Larnu: then it still giving result whether in col2 is having A or B. What I want is col2 having only both A and B.

Comment: Works fine for me: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=403db377b0c1b9fe1a71b140773ab841). This returns both rows that you want in your expected results. I can't say i follow why that `WHERE` won't work, based on your small sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    col1    VARCHAR(32),
    col2    VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT @Test (col1, col2)
VALUES
('nameA', 'A'),
('nameA', 'B'),
('nameB', 'A'),
('nameC', 'B')

SELECT col1, col2
FROM @Test t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @Test
    WHERE col1 = t.col1
        AND col2 != t.col2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following aggregation query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT col1
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE col2 IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING MIN(col2) <> MAX(col2) AND COUNT(*) = 2
)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte t2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1);
```

As a note about the aggregation logic in the CTE, I restrict to only `col1` groups which have only `A` and `B` values for `col2` *and* only groups having exactly two records (i.e. multiple `A` and `B` is not acceptable).  With the CTE having done most of the heavy lifting, to find the full matching records we only need a simple select against your table with an `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: i see a little snafu. what if there are 2 A's and 1 B?

Comment: @KeithL According to my interpretation of the OP, that case should fail.  If the OP wants to accept that case, then just remove `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`.

Comment: I dont want to use CTE since I'm using CASE here. Can we do it in WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no duplicates in your table, window functions are an easy solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(case when col2 in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 2;
```

This nicely generalizes to more than two columns.

Answer (score -1):

```
where col1 = 'nameA' and (col2 = 'A' or col2 = 'B')
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation with your answer please. Answers with just one line of code without explanation often get downvoted